# Can a directory file be gathered and renamed to a new name in runfiles using filegroup for cc_test data dependency?

Tags: c++, bazel

I have a question about cc_test data dependency. I want to gather a directory file and rename this directory name to a new name in runfiles, like the pkg_files prefix. Is it possible for data dependency using filegroup?

I have tried using pkg_tar and pkg_files to achieve above goal.

```
cc_test(
    name = "my_test",
    srcs = ["src/test.cc"],
    data = [
        ":data_artifacts",
    ],
    deps = [
       "some_deps"
    ],
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "data_files",
    srcs = [
        "//my/this_is_a_pkg_files_deps:data", # a pkg_files deps
    ],
    include_runfiles = True,
    mode = "0644",
)

genrule(
    name = "data_artifacts",
    srcs = [
        ":data_files",
    ],
    outs = [
        "artifacts",
    ],
    cmd = " && ".join([
        "mkdir $@",
        "tar xf $(location :data_files) -C $@",
    ]),
)
```

The above bazel give me a warning:

```
output '//my/artifacts' of //my:data_artifacts is a directory; dependency checking of directories is unsound
```